# How to disable SSL on domain

Tags: wordpress, http, https, subdomain

I am trying to make a http request on https, i am getting this error [error: mixed content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMoqG.png). I try this but the error stays

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: mixed content means that the content is delivered through HTTPS but your HTML references images/CSS/JS/fonts/etc. with HTTP URLs. There is nothing to do at the webserver, you need to fix your HTML content. Any browser development tools should be able to tell you which URLs are the culprit.

Comment: thank you @PatrickMevzek